# Protractor: run all tests by ignoring iit/xit/ddescribe/

Tags: automated-tests, protractor

if multiple persons work on different protractor front-end-tests, ill see them check-in tests with active "iit", "xit", "ddescribe" and so on. They simply forget to remove the leading "i", "x", "d" before version-conrol-system checkin.

If another developer or a central CI-System will run those tests, protractor will just execute the marked tests.

Is there a way to configure protractor to execute all tests by ignoring those marked test cases and simply run all tests?

Answer (score 4):

Protractor uses minijasminenode (https://github.com/juliemr/minijasminenode/tree/jasmine1) to modify Jasmine to run in node. minijasminenode does not allow ignore 'iit' or 'ddescribe'.

I would suggested having your CI run a check to ensure that no one checks in code with iit or ddescribe in it. Angular's CI has a check like this using grunt: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/36831eccd1da37c089f2141a2c073a6db69f3e1d/Gruntfile.js#L237

Comment: Thanks Julie, that helped me a lot! But your comment was a little bit unclear at first. Here for all other interested in this:

You have to install the npm-package "grunt-ddescribe-iit" and setup the following inside your Gruntfile.js

**grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ddescribe-iit'); // Somewhere inside module.exports**

and

**'ddescribe-iit': { ... } // Like in Jmr's second link as a grunt-task (inside grunt.init)**